# How to unpack a tuple for looping without being dimension specific

Tags: python, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array, tuples

I'd like to do something like this:

```
    if dim==2:
        a,b=grid_shape
        for i in range(a):
            for j in range(b):
                A[i,j] = ...things...
```

where `dim` is simply the number of elements in my tuple `grid_shape`. `A` is a numpy array of dimension `dim`.
Is there a way to do it without being dimension specific? 
Without having to write ugly code like

```
    if dim==2:
        a,b=grid_shape
        for i in range(a):
            for j in range(b):
                A[i,j] = ...things...
    if dim==3:
        a,b,c=grid_shape
        for i in range(a):
            for j in range(b):
                for k in range(c):
                    A[i,j,k] = ...things...
```

Comment: IIUC, you're looking for [ndenumerate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697274/iterate-over-numpy-matrix-of-unknown-dimension).  Can you confirm?

Comment: Not exactly, even though that function will turn out to be useful in other part of the routine, so thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using itertools, you can do it like this:

```
for index in itertools.product(*(range(x) for x in grid_shape)):
    A[index] = ...things...
```

This relies on a couple of tricks.  First, `itertools.product()` is a function which generates tuples from iterables.

```
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        index = i,j
        do_something_with(index)
```

can be reduced to

```
for index in itertools.product(range(a),range(b)):
    do_something_with(index)
```

This works for any number of arguments to `itertools.product()`, so you can effectively create nested loops of arbitrary depth.

The other trick is to convert your grid shape into the arguments for itertools.product:

```
(range(x) for x in grid_shape)
```

is equivalent to

```
(range(grid_shape[0]),range(grid_shape[1]),...)
```

That is, it is a tuple of ranges for each grid_shape dimension.  Using * then expands this into the arguments.

```
itertools.product(*(range(x1),range(x2),...))
```

is equivalent to

```
itertools.product(range(x1),range(x2),...)
```

Also, since `A[i,j,k]` is equivalent to `A[(i,j,k)]`, we can just use `A[index]` directly.

As [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) points out, since you are using numpy, you can reduce

```
itertools.product(*(for range(x) for x in grid_shape))
```

to

```
numpy.ndindex(grid_shape)
```

So the final loop becomes

```
for index in numpy.ndindex(grid_shape):
    A[index] = ...things...
```

Comment: This seems to work!
Could you please explain to me the machinery behind it?

Comment: See `np.ndindex`, if all we want is the index and not the value.

Comment: You've both been extremely useful! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the rest of the tuple by putting a star in front of the last variable and make a an array by putting parentheses around it.

```
>>> tupl = ((1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> a, *b = tupl
>>> a
(1, 2)
>>> b
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

And then you can loop through b. So it would look something like

```
a,*b=grid_shape
for i in a:
    for j in range(i):
        for k in b:
            for l in range(k):
                A[j, l] = ...things...
```

Comment: This won't work, because A will turn out to be a 2-dimensional array even if b has more than one element.

Comment: does that fix it?